# Pass String Variable Data from one Class/ViewController to Class/ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, class, variables, uiviewcontroller

I have two viewControllers: 
1. CheckoutVC
2. DeliveryTimeVC

In DeliveryTimeVC I have the following variable:

```
class DeliveryTimeVC: UIViewController {
var tableViewDay:String = ""
}
```

I use the following push to go from `CheckoutVC` to `DeliveryTimeVC`:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Storyboard.DeliveryTimeStoryboard, bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryboardId.DeliveryTimeVC)
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

In `DeliveryTimeVC` I have a tableView where on didSelect I go back to `CheckoutVC` and in `didSelect` func I have the following code to append my variable before leaving the controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
tableViewDay.removeAll()
tableViewDay.append(cell.weekDayLbl.text!)
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

How can I transfer the String variable data from `DeliveryTimeVC` to another variable in `CheckoutVC`? Lets say I create a variable in CheckoutVC as:

```
class CheckoutVC: UIViewController, CartProductCellDelegate {
var tableViewDayTransferedData:String = ""
}
```

How can I transfer the data from `tableViewDay:String` to `tableViewDayTransferedData:String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Hassan Shahbazi comment above I was able to change his code slightly and get the final answer that works for me:

```
protocol DeliveryTimeDelegate: class {
   func didGetData(tableViewDayTransferedData: String)
}

class DeliveryTimeVC: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: DeliveryTimeDelegate?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableViewDay.removeAll()
        tableViewDay.append(cell.weekDayLbl.text!)

        delegate?.didGetData(tableViewDayTransferedData: tableViewDay)
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}

class CheckoutVC: UIViewController, DeliveryTimeDelegate {
    func ...() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Storyboard.DeliveryTimeStoryboard, bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryboardId.DeliveryTimeVC) as! DeliveryTimeVC
        controller.delegate = self
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }

    func didGetData(tableViewDayTransferedData: String) {
        tableViewDayTransferedData = tableViewDayTransferedData
    }
}
```

in the last func you see two same variables; they just have the same name: `tableViewDayTransferedData = tableViewDayTransferedData` first one is from CheckoutVC. the second one is from the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

well you can use this lines

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NAMEOFYOURSTORYBOARD", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IDOFYOURVIEW") as! CheckoutVC
vc.tableViewDayTransferedData = self. tableViewDay
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: How is that passing the variable data I asked for?

Answer (score 0):

There are generally 2 main patterns for data/variable passing in iOS.

### Delegate Pattern

The popular pattern for Objective-c days, but still useful and easy to do. You'll need to define a `delegate protocol` and use it for passing variables.

```swift
protocol DeliveryTimeDelegate: class {
   func didGetData(tableViewDay: String)
}

class DeliveryTimeVC: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: DeliveryTimeDelegate?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableViewDay.removeAll()
        tableViewDay.append(cell.weekDayLbl.text!)

        delegate?.didGetData(tableViewDay: "YOUR_VALUE")
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}

class CheckoutVC: UIViewController, CartProductCellDelegate {
    func ...() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Storyboard.DeliveryTimeStoryboard, bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryboardId.DeliveryTimeVC)
        controller.delegate = self
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}

extension CheckoutVC: DeliveryTimeDelegate {
    func didGetData(tableViewDay: String) {
        tableViewDayTransferedData = tableViewDay
    }
}
```

### Closure Pattern

The pattern could be seen as the **swift** friendly implementation of `delegate`. It's important to pay enough attention to memory management and retain cycle issues when you're using `closure`.

```swift
class DeliveryTimeVC: UIViewController {
    var onDataTransfered: ((String) -> Void)?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableViewDay.removeAll()
        tableViewDay.append(cell.weekDayLbl.text!)

        self.onDataTransfered?("YOUR_VALUE")
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}

class CheckoutVC: UIViewController, DeliveryTimeDelegate {
    func ...() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Storyboard.DeliveryTimeStoryboard, bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryboardId.DeliveryTimeVC)
        controller.onDataTransfered = { [weak self] tableViewDayTransferedData in
            self?.tableViewDay = tableViewDayTransferedData
        }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just following your first solution (Delegate) and it all went well until the last func in CheckoutVC. When I try to type `tableViewDay = tableViewDayTransferedData` it does not recognize `tableViewDay` do you know why?

Comment: Also the second func for ChecoutVC when I type `controller.delegate = self` I get an error: `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'delegate'` But I have changed my class to: `class CheckoutVC: UIViewController, CartProductCellDelegate, DeliveryTimeDelegate`

Comment: @Farhadam I updated the answer, check if it solves your problem now.

Comment: I posted an answer below; it is almost identical to your pre-edit post. Have a look and it worked for me. I had to make only two small changes in the last two func and it worked like a charm!